# intensive MySQL query offloading

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

let's say I had an intensive query that is going to be done many times each second, like a busy site with complex a complex filtering. Here is a sample of the query:

```
SELECT
SUM(t.qty_inv) / t.deck_cards completed,
t.deck_id
FROM (
  SELECT
  CASE WHEN m.qty_inv IS NULL THEN 0 WHEN m.qty_inv > dc.card_qty THEN dc.card_qty ELSE m.qty_inv END qty_inv,
  dc.deck_id,
  d.deck_cards
  FROM mtgb_test.decks d
  INNER JOIN mtgb_test.decks_cards dc ON (d.deck_id = dc.deck_id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
    COUNT(*) qty_inv, item_print_id print_id
    FROM mtgb_test.inventories_items
    WHERE item_user_id = 1
    GROUP BY item_print_id
  ) m ON (m.print_id = dc.card_print_id)
) t
GROUP BY deck_id
ORDER BY completed DESC;
```

This is going to be done to some 200,000 records, which I assume is going to be intensive for the DB if done simultaneously (e.g. multiple users searching at the same time). Is there any specialized software or methodology I can use where so can offload this intense processing to? I have heard of [sphinx search](http://www.sphinxsearch.com) and all the good feedback about it, but I believe it's only good for text searches? My query is more on joining fields by id's and counting percentages.

Comment: Consider something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to cache the results of these queries. This will be effective if decks don't change particularly often.

Comment: decks dont change often but inventories of the person searching them do. and the decks table will frequently change I guess because people add them all the time.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be server intensive if you use query cache. Just take a look at this documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html

When you turn on query cache, it will return the same result (if the data has not changed) without doing the search over and over again.